# adding/ updating list with excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, updating

this might be easy for you but i am new at VBA.

I have Excel file which has many columns with one of them being "id", which is a key value. I wrote a code to open a selection for the file;

```
  Sub GetFile()
 Dim fNameAndPath As Variant
fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files    (*.XLSM), *.XLSM", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
  If fNameAndPath = False Then
   Exit Sub
Workbooks.Open Filename:=fNameAndPath
End Sub
```

I would like to have macro in this list, which should add the other files( which have same column Names with different values and uncertain amount of rows). And if the "id" column has same value in added file, the old ones row should be entirely deleted.

Does anyone have any Suggestion?

Comment: yeah exactly this. i want to be able to select any amount of file while i do this. And if "id" column values already same, it will delete the old one in the list.

Comment: i know how to open a file selection, but i dont know how i will add the other file values to the list if they are variable (some of the file has 10 values some of them 100 etc), if they are not variable i could do it with record macro. Additionally, i do not know the algorithm which checks if two values are same and deletes the old one.

Comment: i have edited it and i dont get any response

Comment: OK... step by step. You have the code to open up the other files. What is the next step? Open them up automatically or just use the manual opened files, or what are you heading next?

Comment: when i open the selection Folder, i should be able to open up anything which is inside of that Folder. for example if there is 5 files inside, then These 5 files should be opened and merged in to that list, when its 3 then 3 and so on... but if opening These manually is easier to reach, then that should be fine to, so i can select These manually as well.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your first problem I suggest something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim myWorkbooks As New Collection

Sub GetFile()
  Dim fNameAndPath As Variant, i As Long, x As Variant
  fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files    (*.*), *.*", , "Select Files To Be Opened", , True)

  If Not IsArray(fNameAndPath) Then
    If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub Else fNameAndPath = Array(fNameAndPath)
  End If

  For i = LBound(fNameAndPath) To UBound(fNameAndPath)
    Set x = Workbooks.Open(fNameAndPath(i))
    myWorkbooks.Add x
  Next
End Sub
```

This allows you to open multiple files and also stores them (a pointer to them).
You can access them later like this:

```
Sub ChkID(ID As String)
  Dim x As Variant
  For Each x In myWorkbooks

    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(ID, x.Sheets(1).Columns(1), 0)) Then
      x.Sheets(1).Rows(Application.Match(ID, x.Sheets(1).Columns(1), 0)).Delete xlUp
      x.Save

    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

This would check Column A of the first sheet in each workbook if it contains the ID and if yes, deleting the line.

If you are finished with everything, you can close/save all the wb's via:

```
Sub ClsFile()
  While myWorkbooks.Count
    myWorkbooks(1).Close True
    myWorkbooks.Remove 1
  Wend
End Sub
```

The only downside is, that if VBA needs to be stopped, then the collection will be empty again (you would need to close them manually and the open them up again via the sub.

---

This should contain all you need to build your own code the way you need it. But if you still have any questions, just ask :)

Comment: thanks a lot, i ll try it now! i have one more question. How can i find the code which adds the values of other files to the next empty row ?

Comment: Just look for "find first empty row" or "get last used row" or something like that... google will show millions of possibilities (ok... just the links to them)  :P